# Storing custom project related data in the Eclipse .project file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

The project I'm working on has its own nature. The project has its own preferences that can be set by a user. I would like to store these preferences in the .project file - it would allow to easily exchange of the project between the users (the user who wants to share the project with someone else doesn't have to export it).
The question is - **is it possible to store additional (custom) data in the `.project` file in Eclipse's project?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it should be possible, but this is not recommended and is not common practise. The `.project` file is bound to the interface `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription`. If you need shareable project-specific settings does it like all other Eclipse plugins, e.g. JDT, PDE, etc. Create your own `.settings/.myspecificprops` file use this file for serialization of your values and make that accessible through your `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectNature` implementation. The written files are also located in the project-folder, so that there is no need to export them.